# Nginx redirect inside a folder

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, directory

I need nginx redirect rules to redirect www and NON-www domain inside folder
For example I need www.domain.com and domain.com to permanently redirect to domain.com/folder.

All I have managed to complete is to redirect www.domain.com to domain.com/wp and it works fine but when I try to add the same with domain.com to redirect to domain.com/wp I`m getting redirect loop.

This one is working but how to add domain.com to redirect in domain.com/folder without cousin redirect loop?

```
if ($host = 'www.domain.com' ) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain.com/folder/$1 permanent; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to add the following location on the configuration for the domain.com server block:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com/folder$request_uri;
}
```

And use this on the domain.com block:

```
    location /folder {
        root /var/www/path/to/folder;
    }
```

Using this additional block, I believe that you can stop using the if